# Multiple thread prints mixed together

Tags: python, multithreading, thread-safety

I'm experimenting with multithreading for the first time. I'm using `Queue.Queue` and putting data in there after I've created a set of objects that inherit from `threading.Thread`. The script downloads a series of files and works perfectly fine, I have it downloading and it has proven much faster than my old one.

However, my thread begins with a print command to show that it has begun downloading. Just a simple "Downloading C:\foo.bar". When the queue is first created, all these print commands are stuck together, and then the newlines all appear afterwards.

Here's a basic idea of the code involved:

```
import Queue
import threading

queue = Queue.Queue()

class ThreadDownload(threading.Thread):
    """Threaded Download"""

    def __init__(self, queue):
        threading.Thread.__init__(self)
        self.queue = queue

    def run(self):
        while True:
            data = self.queue.get()

            print ("Downloading {}".format(data))
            #download_file(data)
            time.sleep(10)

            self.queue.task_done()

for i in range(4):
    t = ThreadDownload(queue)
    t.setDaemon(True)
    t.start()

#for d in data:
for d in range(20):
    queue.put(d)

queue.join()
```

Note that `download_file` is a function from a 3rd party library that people are unlikely to know or have easy access to so I've left it out in favour of people putting some other time consuming call for their testing. Likewise with `data`, the form of data is irrelevant to the question so instead I suggest people use `range` in order to test easily.

Here's what output might look like:

```
Downloading C:\foo.barDownloading C:\foo.barDownloading C:\foo.barDownloading C:\foo.bar



Downloading C:\foo.bar
Downloading C:\foo.bar
Downloading C:\foo.bar
```

The reason seems to be because of the fact that these threads are starting their run simultaneously. If I add `time.sleep(0.01)` I can prevent it but that's a hacky approach. And I'm also concerned that this could mean that if two downloads coincidentally started at the same split second it would happen again.

Is there any way to actually enforce a separation here so I don't get this problem? I have heard that you shouldn't have threads handle UI, that's usually in the context of something like redrawing a progress bar though. Also I'm not sure if there's a convenient way to note when an item from the queue has been taken by a thread, but perhaps I've missed it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have a queue with a single thread (call it the console thread) that is responsible for writing the messages out. To write something you generate the output then put it in the queue and the console thread will write it correctly when it gets to it.

This way there's a single thread responsible for writing stuff to console and you can control exactly how things should be outputted.

Comment: This is an interesting solution, it seems like it'd be a bit clunky and hard to read though. Do you know if this is a common approach to UI handling from threads?

Answer (score 0):

An implementation of [Sorin](https://stackoverflow.com/users/241013/sorin)'s [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32841380/240845):

```
# printt.py
from __future__ import annotations
from queue import Queue
import threading
from typing import Optional, TextIO

class _Param:
    def __init__(self,
                 *args,
                 sep: str=' ',
                 end: str='\n',
                 file: Optional[TextIO]=None,
                 flush: bool=False):
        self._args = args
        self._sep: str = sep
        self._end: str = end
        self._file: TextIO = file
        self._flush: bool = flush

    @property
    def args(self):
        return self._args

    @property
    def sep(self) -> str:
        return self._sep

    @property
    def end(self) -> str:
        return self._end

    @property
    def file(self) -> Optional[TextIO]:
        return self._file

    @property
    def flush(self) -> bool:
        return self._flush

_print_queue: Queue[_Param] = Queue()


def _printer():
    while True:
        p = _print_queue.get()
        print(*p.args, sep=p.sep, end=p.end, file=p.file, flush=p.flush)


_print_task = threading.Thread(target=_printer)
_print_task.start()


def printt(*args,
           sep: str=' ',
           end: str='\n',
           file: Optional[TextIO]=None,
           flush: bool=False):
    """
    print(value, ..., sep=' ', end='\n', file=sys.stdout, flush=False)

    Thread safe print. Prints the values to a stream, or to sys.stdout by default.
    Optional keyword arguments:
    sep:   string inserted between values, default a space.
    end:   string appended after the last value, default a newline.
    file:  a file-like object (stream); defaults to the current sys.stdout.
    flush: whether to forcibly flush the stream.
    """
    _print_queue.put(_Param(*args, sep=sep, end=end, file=file, flush=flush))
```

Obviously, for fully thread safe print, you have to use `printt()` everywhere you would have used [print()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#print) because it just serializes the use of [print()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#print) under the hood.